# Changing site width with media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am in some dire need of help. I am so close to finishing my final but I don't quite understand media queries. I have to "include a media query to change the page to fit on a tablet and a mobile query. You will be shrinking the width of the page to fit. You will also be turning off visibility to an image of your choice."

He didn't go over it too well and I've been scouring sites in confusion. Now I'm not sure what sizes to use or if I need to code a completely new layout for the phone and tablet. I just need some guidance please.

Not sure if code is needed for this but I'll include one page and the css just in case:

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#nav {
   float: right;
   width: 500px;
   height: 700px;
   background-color: #6C8822;
   color: black;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   margin-right: 50px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   text-align: center;
}

#links {
 margin-top: 20px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 35px;
 margin-top: 70px;

}

a:hover {
 color: #645399;
 
}

#linkborder1 {
 border: 2px dotted white;
 padding: 5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}

#linkborder2 {
 border: 2px dotted white;
 padding: 5px;
 padding-left: 34px;
 padding-right: 34px;
}

#linkborder1:hover {
 border-color: #645399;
}

#linkborder2:hover {
 border-color: #645399;
}

#header {
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 background-color: #6C8822;
 color: white;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: Comic San MS;
}

body {
 background-image: url("images/bg1.jpg");
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

html {
 overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

img {
 margin-left: 25px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-right: 25px;
}

p {
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #CCD994;
}

#textbio {
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#imagemap {
 margin-left: 80px;
}

video {
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 105px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 width: 1280px;
 height: 720;
}


#imagemap, #vid {
 display : inline;
 position: relative;
    left:50px;
}

caption {
 font-size: 24px;
}

th {
 background-color: #CCD994;
}

td {
 height: 50px;
 border-bottom: 1.5px dashed;
 width: 300px;
}

tfoot {
 background-color: gray;
}

table {
 table-layout: auto;
 width: 15%;
 float: right;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 background-color: #6C8822;
 position: relative; 
 margin: -500px;
 margin-top: 480px;
}

div.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
z-index: -1
}

#pics {
 margin-left: 250px;
 padding: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#table {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 50px;
 width: 600px;
 height: 700px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

#form {
 float: center;
 background-color: #6C8822;
 margin: 15px;
 margin-left: 500px;
 width: 600px;
 font-size: 36px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}

input {
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

select {
 font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Page 2</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="finalcss.css">
</head>


<div id="header" class="center">
 <h1>Final Project</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
 <img src="images/me.png" alt="Me in Animal Crossing" width="350" height="300">
  <div class="textbio">
   <p>Hey I'm Jay, this is my final project! It's not much but I worked hard on it, hope you enjoy!!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="links">
   <a id="linkborder1" href="final.html">Home</a>
   <br>
   <br>
   <a id="linkborder2" href="final2.html">P2</a>
   <br>
   <br>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="body">
 <div id="pics">
  <img src="images/padme.png" alt="" width="450px" height="450px">
  <img src="images/sqs.png" alt="" width="450px" height="450px">
  <br>
  <img src="images/reese.jpg" alt="" width="450px" height="450px">
  <img src="images/lotus.png" alt="" width="450px" height="450px">
 </div>
</div>
 
<div id="table" class="fixed">
<table class="center">
  <Caption><b>Commission</b></Caption>
  
  <thead align="center">
  <th colspan="5"><b>Type</b></th>
  <th><b>Price Range</b></th>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody align="center">
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5">Icon</td>
   <td>$5-$15</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5">Half-Body</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5">Full-Body</td>
   <td>$5-$25</td>
  </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
 
<div id="form">
<Caption><b> Contact Form</b></Caption>
<table>
  <thead align="center">
  
  </thead>
  
  <tbody align="center">
    <br>
    <br>
  <fieldset>
   <legend></legend>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="40">
    <br>
    <br>
    Address Line 1: <input type="text" name="addressline1" size="40">
    <br>
    <br>
    Address Line 2: <input type="text" name="addressline2" size="40">
    <br>
    <br>
    City: <input type="text" name="city" size="40">
    <br>
    <br>
    State: <input type="text" name="state" size="40">
    <br>
    <br>
    Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zipcode" size="40">
    <br>
    <br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="40">
    <br>
    <br>
    Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phonenumber" size="40">
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="Contact Times">
     <option value="morning">Morning</option>
     <option value="afternoon">Afternoon</option>
     <option value="evening">Evening</option>
    </select>
   
  </fieldset>

   
  </tbody>

 </table>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you are missing `<body> </body>` tags. Check out the correct structure here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Comment: I'm aware, I'm using <div></div> in their place, but thanks for the heads up!

Comment: They are not something you're supposed to swap out...

Comment: @Kaiju You can't switch out the `<body>` tags for `<div>`s. That is straight wrong.

Comment: @GBWDev (tagging you as well since you mentioned it too) Really? My web development professor did it so I thought it was fine. But thanks for telling me! Would just putting <body></body> around <div id="body"></div> be fine?

Comment: No, place the `<body>` tag directly after the closing `</head>` tag and place the closing  `</body>` tag directly above the closing `</html>` tag. The body tags should contain all of your HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as i can see you are just a starter, first of all you need to use viewport code to get the page working on all different devices, the view port code is below.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

after this inside your CSS file you will need to use media query, this is a break point where you see the design/website/page is not usable at some browser width, at this with you will need to add media query like:

`@media query and (max-width: 400px){ // here you should update the broken css code}`

if you don't use the view port your query won't work, also you need to add `<body></body>` to your code, it's not required by the modern browsers but you have to do it as the older browsers won't understand your code and your page will be broken and not usable.

some more information can be found below:

[Media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

[another Media query source (CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

[HTML5 responsive web pages W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

hope this help

Answer (score 1):

You've already given some good sources, here is a small example how to use media queries in your CSS. Just add device specific styles inside the brackets.

```
// everything mobile and above

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    // everything mobile landscape and above
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    // everything tablet and above
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    // everything notebook and above
}
```

Example with a little explaination in the comments.

```
// everything mobile and above
.someClass {
    width: 200px; // base style
    background: green; // style for all devices, since not overridden
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    // everything notebook and above
    .someClass {
       width: 400px; // overrides mobile style for notebook and above
       color: red; // only for notebook and above
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be a silly question but how exactly do you style them? I've been trying but no differences have appeared.

Comment: @Kaiju I've added a little extra example, I hope this helps.